# Strata statement in SAS proc logistic

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

Do the characteristics of the strata summary table (the information regarding the strata statement in `proc logistic` on the SAS User Guide) apply to non-exact `proc logistic` or only to exact logistic regression?
More specifically, where it says that strata with only events or only non-events are uninformative and are not included in the analysis --is this statement applicable to all strata summary tables in `proc logistic`? I am doing a 1:6 matched case-control study and using conditional logistic regression. I want to make sure that where my cases are dropped for having missing covariate data, the entire strata is excluded in the analysis, even if their matched controls are not technically dropped because they don't have missing data.

Thank you

Here is the SAS User Guide section on this ( I am using 9.4): https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect024.htm

Comment: I don't think that will happen, but it's fairly easy to check. Run it and get an output of predictors and estimates and check if the whole strata was dropped or just the records that contained missing data.

Comment: Which version of SAS/STAT are you using? You can find it by running the following: `proc product_status;run;` and it should likely be 14.3 or 14.2 is my guess. I doubt it matters, but versions can vary.